# highcharts pie monochrome: how to set the default color?

Tags: highcharts

i'm not sure where/how to set the default color for a monochrome pie.  i want the initial color to be, for example, purple with monochrome fill throughout. how do you set it in the monochrome pie example taken from the highcharts website?

**code from the highcharts website:**

```
$(function () {

    // Make monochrome colors and set them as default for all pies
    Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions.pie.colors = (function () {
        var colors = [],
            base = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
            // Start out with a darkened base color (negative brighten), and end
            // up with a much brighter color
            colors.push(Highcharts.Color(base).brighten((i - 3) / 7).get());
        }
        return colors;
    }());

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should change `base = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]` to:

```
base = '#9900CC'
```

Which the code is for your new color. Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e7rr74Ls/)

Comment: @Dana why do you ask a question when you are not around to see the answer to?